# "scale_x_date()" with uneven date breaks - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a dataset where the dates are not evenly spaced. By using scale_x_date(), I get the axis labels in a chronological orde, but the extra dates in between are also included (which I need to eliminate). The attached pic should give the entire picture. Basically, I don't want the gaps in between. Thanks. [Take a look at the axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKMH.png)

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2018-06-11", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-27", "2018-06-01", "2018-06-05"),
                 A=c(5, 3, 2, 7, 8))
df$date <- factor(format.Date(df$date, "%d-%b"), ordered = TRUE)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%b")

bp <- ggplot(df,
             aes(x = date, y = A),
             main = 'Bar Plot')
bp +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'orange', width = 0.50) + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = df$date, date_labels = "%d-%b")
```

Comment: What are you tried so far.? Please post the code that you tired.

Comment: The answer that is mentioned does not help my case.
1. The date format changes back to "YYYY-MM-DD" which is undesirable to me.
2. The spaces still exist between two valid dates

Comment: @Jayendran I have tried to convert it to ordered factor. After this, the gaps are not there but the chronological order is disturbed